# Change the font size of chart.js with chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chart.js, chartkick

first of all, please excuse my english.

I'm a junior developer on Ruby on Rails and I developed an user management application, among other things. I'm working on the last feature that is generating statistics in a PDF using Chartkick and WickedPDF.

But, I have a problem because the generated JS has a very tiny font size. I tried everything, but nothing to do, I can not enlarge this font.

Here is the line that generates one of my graphs :

```
    <%= pie_chart Infosheet.group(:gender).count, library: {FontSize: 90} %>
```

This generate this code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       new Chartkick.PieChart("chart-1", {"man":4}, {"library":{"FontSize":90}});
    </script>
```

But nothing change. I tried lots of other things that I do not have in mind anymore... In my PDF, the graph has a gigantic margin and a tiny font. :/

I despair because I have to return the project next week.

Can someone help me?

thank you very much

**EDIT :**

This is my statistics in my PDF :

https://i.gyazo.com/c86a39b2a9e529b7551f8654bee838b4.mp4

The font is... really tiny. my statistics have a size of 5000px x 5000px.
Also, nothing changes if I increase the dpi of PDF

**RESOLVED :**

Finally, I forked chartkick to change the font-size directly into it, as no option was passed.

Comment: just a guess but try `{fontSize: 90}`

Comment: Thank for your reply, I believed it, but unfortunately it is not that. :(

Comment: what does the chart look like in the web app before PDF ?

Comment: My statistics are not supposed to appear outside the PDF but I created a chart on a page to test the options without having to reload the PDF each time. Here it is readable but none of the options in the library works : https://i.gyazo.com/cca844fa7264c2e3c81c1bcc9f410add.png          But in my PDF, either the graphics do not appear, or they are tiny. I managed to enlarge them but only the size of the graph changes, not the font it contains ...

Comment: Did you solve this? and how?

Answer (score 3):

There you are

```rb
  <%= pie_chart counters, library: { legend: { position: "left", labels: { fontSize: 26 } } } %>
```

Comment: This is worked after I added this gem gem 'chart-js-rails'

Answer (score 0):

I think you're passing the attribute with wrong case.  Should probably be `snakeCase` and also try using a pixel size like so:

```
<%= pie_chart Infosheet.group(:gender).count, library: {fontSize: "50px"} %>


<script type="text/javascript">
   new Chartkick.PieChart("chart-1", {"man":4}, {"library":{"fontSize":"50px"}});
</script>
```

Comment: I believed it, but unfortunately it is not that. :(

Comment: updated answer, did you try maybe with `px` in font size?

Comment: Yes I tried but nothing change... Maybe I'll have to use chart.js directly, if I find how to put the data in DB

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<%= pie_chart Infosheet.group(:gender).count, library: {fontSize: 90} %>
```